# php parsers to turn user query into solr query?

Tags: php, solr, transform

i am looking around for any parsers that would help me format the user query into a solr query, any hints what modules might help me out here?

note: i am not asking about the solr php clients that do the communication, i am talking about the preparation of the correct query string

Answer (score 0):

The [DisMax request handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxRequestHandler) was designed precisely for this: accepting user input as is. No need to use any specific PHP parsers. Just send the user input to the dismax handler using the PHP client library. Of course, you might want to configure dismax to your needs, but that's server-side, not client-side (i.e. not in PHP)

Comment: that would force the user to use whatever syntax DisMax accepts, which will not work. so, basically i am looking for some kind of lexer module in php that converts from one grammatic into another.

Comment: @JohnSmith: No. DisMax accepts whatever the user inputs. The user does not need to know about any syntax. Take a look at the wiki.

Comment: I meant, we need to parse the current user input we accept (with custom special operators that we need to map to corresponding operators that Solr accepts). E.g. "dog ^ cat" would search for "dog AND cat" in the current system, its an old legacy system built in the 80s that we now are replacing with a web based system, but need to accept the old user input since the users are used to it.

Comment: @JohnSmith: you should mention that in the question.